# How do I retain column headers when executing stored procedure using python?

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

After I run my code shown below, I receive all the data from my stored procedure. However, the column names are not returned:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=PMI0317\Prod;'
                      'Database=Warehouse;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                      )

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SET NOCOUNT ON;EXEC Test.storedproc')
results = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
df
```

Output[113]:

```
             0   1                  2   3    4    5   ... 15  16  17  18 19 20
0       9593746   0  COOKCHILDRENS.ORG   1  1.0  Dog  ...  0   0   0   0  0  2
1       9593723   0          gmail.com   1  1.0  Dog  ...  0   0  12  16  0  0
list(df.columns)
Out[114]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

As you see, it returns my data but column names are changes to numeric. why does this happen? What do I need to change in results function to retain original column names?

Comment: you know you could directly execute sql and load it into pandas using `pd.read_sql_query`

Comment: ive tried df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM EXEC warehouse.Test.storedproc ", conn) already but I get an error saying syntax error near 'EXEC'. So i used this long method instead

Comment: it should be only "EXEC warehouse.Test.storedproc"

Comment: also maybe try this wrapper `pd.read_sql`

Comment: pd.read_sql works and not _query for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the column name from cursor description:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results, columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description])
```

alternatively, you could use `read_sql` and directly load into pandas :

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=PMI0317\Prod;'
                      'Database=Warehouse;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                      )

df = pd.read_sql('exec Test.storedproc',conn)
```

Comment: Works. Want to mark this answer correct but have to wait for 5 min acc to SO